# Tagging best practice for N/A or ALL tags (tagging language for images)

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, managed-metadata, term-store, tagging

I'm wondering how to correctly tag documents when the tag doesn't apply to it. The best exemple is trying to tag an image with a language tag.

Which solution is the best with sharepoint 2013 :

1° Create a tag N/A amongst the language tag (English, French, German, etc ...). However, users might get confuse and tag wrongly. Worst, user might look for documents in english by default and miss information stored as images.

2° Tag all languages knowing that if I add a language later (swedish) it will not  be tagged on previously introduced image.

3° Using hierachical managed metadata and create a Tag "ALL" which has subtag "English", "French", "German". Therefore creating a hierarchy.

4° Does it exist other options like a generic tag which would select all tag even the one we add in the future ? like '*'

Answer (score 0):

My personal opinion is that if it doesn't fit into the metadata you've defined, don't tag it with a value.

If requirements dictate that all items must be tagged, then you'll need to supply values that suit the need, so you'd have to have an All Categories tag, * isn't very friendly, and a No Category tag for items that don't match.

Blank values are fine and still can be filtered on, so if it doesn't fit into the taxonomy, don't tag it.